# Circular navigation style

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use [this](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CircularNavigation/index.html) `navigation` style in my web that will run on `Safari browser` mostly.
In this there is an `anchor tag` in every `li` (total 5 `li`). Every `anchor` has different value in `href`. But when i move mouse cursor on first (or second,third,fourth) `anchor` it shows the `href` of last `anchor` `tag`. So when I click on any `anchor` `tag` it will goes on last `anchor's` `href`.

Here is my [`demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/ZF4C4/)

Comment: I cannot edit your question personally, but if you could edit the grammar, provide living examples of your code snippets. maybe some thing you tried to no avail. Maybe even a jsfiddle of the problem. A well-worded question leads to better answers. :)

Comment: Thanks @Brendan :)  I updated my question hope it will good enough now

Comment: Much better, this I can work with! Thank you.

Comment: It's quite odd, but my debugger shows that each `<a>` tag is acting over the entire navigation wheel. The reason the last one is working is because its the last one in the list. Ill look into fixing it..

Comment: Odly enough, deleting the last item in the list lets the next item become the link for everything. curious. I think I'm reaching an answer...

Comment: i think i figure it out my links now working but border radius not work now it will show rectangular shape now.
For links i remove this line `position: fixed; /* fix the "displacement" bug in webkit browsers when using tab key */` from a class `.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a`

Comment: check this one now links working :) http://jsfiddle.net/ZF4C4/2/

Comment: Write your solution as an answer so others can benefit if they ever have a problem like that. And sorry I wasn't much help in the end after all... Time for another cup of coffee...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve my issue by changing in css
 in this css class

```
.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.18em;
    height: 14.5em;
    width: 14.5em;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -7.25em;
    right: -7.25em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 1.8em;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-50deg) rotate(-70deg) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: skew(-50deg) rotate(-70deg) scale(1);
    -moz-transform: skew(-50deg) rotate(-70deg) scale(1);
    transform: skew(-50deg) rotate(-70deg) scale(1);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, color 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s, color 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s, color 0.3s;
}
```

i remove `position:fixed` from above class (suggested [here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/09/building-a-circular-navigation-with-css-transforms/comment-page-5/#comment-458257)) so now `anchor` `tags` works fine :)

Hope it will help others